# saving data into sql database from textboxes asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have tried so many ways to save textbox text into an SQL database. I just want to save some text from textboxes into an SQL database. I am using 
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and C# programming language. 
Here is my current code:

```js
protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Name = TxtFirstName.Text;
        string Address = TxtDOB.Text;
        string DOB = TxtDOB.Text;
        string Occupation = TxtOccupation.Text;
        string Home = TxtHome.Text;
        string Work = TxtWork.Text;
        string Mobile = TxtMobile.Text;
        string Email = TxtEmail.Text;
        string SportActivities = TxtSportActivities.Text;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ClientsConnectionString"].ConnectionString)) ;
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [ClientDetails] ([Name], [Address], [DOB], [Occupation], [Home], [Work], [Mobile], [Email], [SportActivities]) VALUES ( @Name, @Address, @DOB, @Occupation, @Home, @Work, @Mobile, @Email, @SportActivities)")) ;
            {
                cmd.connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TxtFirstName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", TxtAddress.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", TxtDOB.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occupation", TxtOccupation.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Home", TxtHome.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Work", TxtWork.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", TxtMobile.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TxtEmail.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SportActivities", TxtSportActivities.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

```js
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Name = TxtFirstName.Text;
            string Address = TxtDOB.Text;
            string DOB = TxtDOB.Text;
            string Occupation = TxtOccupation.Text;
            string Home = TxtHome.Text;
            string Work = TxtWork.Text;
            string Mobile = TxtMobile.Text;
            string Email = TxtEmail.Text;
            string SportActivities = TxtSportActivities.Text;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ClientDetailsConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [ClientDetails] ([ID], [Name], [Address], [DOB], [Occupation], [Home], [Work], [Mobile], [Email], [SportActivities]) VALUES (@ID, @Name, @Address, @DOB, @Occupation, @Home, @Work, @Mobile, @Email, @SportActivities)");

            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", TxtID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TxtFirstName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", TxtAddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", TxtDOB.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occupation", TxtOccupation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Home", TxtHome.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Work", TxtWork.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", TxtMobile.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TxtEmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SportActivities", TxtSportActivities.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
```

I have fixed my code. All i did was change 'CodeBehind' to CodeFile' in the aspx.cs file and fixed up some minor errors. Here is my working code:
All i did was remove the brackets as the code didnt recognise 'cmd' and added the 'ID' field as that was the primary key of my database so it had to be there. Everything works great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: all parameters required. post your error message.

Comment: there is no error message.

Comment: add a breakpoint to check weather click event is being called or not ?

Comment: use try..catch to catch exception,  for cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", SqlDbType.Text) pass the value

Comment: @HenryWater check answer for breakpoint

Comment: @HenryWater it seems your button doesn't exist in same page

Comment: It is in the same page below my textboxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add parameter for each of these values:

```
@Name, @Address, @DOB, @Occupation, @Home, @Work, @Mobile, @Email, @SportActivities
```

You used  `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", SqlDbType.Text);` only for name.

EDIT:

There are 2 ways to provide data to sql:
1) Adding parameter by name and later it's value:

```
 command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.Int);
        command.Parameters["@name"].Value = nametextbox.text;
```

2)
Adding parameter with value

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nametextbox.text);
```

Please Use one of them. Not the mix.

EDIT REGARDING ERROR:

> If you use OnClick attribute in the page's HTML view, the name is
>   expected to be on the page script and not in the code-behind. If you
>   want to use a handler in the code-behind, remove OnClick attribute, go
>   to design view and double-click the button. The code-behind will open
>   on the right function. Or you can select event handler in the button
>   properties panel on Events tab. Or you can do it without design view
>   whatsoever. Just go to the code-behind and add a line for registering
>   the event-handling method for the Click event of the button:
>   btnSignIn.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnSignIn_Click);
>
> When you do it in the design view, this line is added to the
>   automatically generated InitializeComponent() method.

Comment: How can we know. It looks ok. Add all others and check. = )

Comment: changed my code and added the other parameters. still not working. There is no error message

Comment: Please edit Question and Add new code there so we can validate.

Comment: i eddited my answer, check it and correct mistakes.

Comment: @HenryWater : regarding error in Question: have you cheked that in the aspx page the button oncClick event is the same name as in the code behind? It sounds to me like they are different, and that is why you are getting the "cannot find" error.

Comment: @JanWalczak yes they are both the same.

Comment: @HenryWater Did You click on botton twice and it took You to this function?

Comment: @JanWalczak yes it did. I even tried adding a new button and copying the code over.

Comment: @HenryWater i added some text to my answer. Maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Click in front of brackets, a red point will come there and again start your process 
[image]

Comment: your event is not being called. double click on button in design view and see where it is going

Comment: you were right. it was going somewhere else. Now i have moved the code and i have a error showing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have lost the link between the button press and the event. You can check this using the Properties Window.

1. display the page containing the asp:Button
2. select the asp:Button
3. Look at the event properties for the asp:button

My guess is that you have lost the link.
So, comment out the event response code and recreate the event.
Use the same process you used to create the event originally.
Then, cut and paste the commented out code you need from the commented out event method. Remove the comment indicators from the pasted code.
Your event should now work.